# Beamer: space between frame title and text

Tags: beamer, spacing, text

I would like the space between the frame title and the text to be the same in all pages. I tried `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2cm}}{\vspace*{-2cm}}` but as you can see in the image below, the space is different.

```
\documentclass[14pt,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{paperwidth=297mm,paperheight=210mm}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2cm}}{\vspace*{-2cm}}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=100pt,text margin right=100pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textbf{Title}}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}
%
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textbf{Title}}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the content of a beamer frame is vertically centered. So what you want to do is align the content at the top. For one frame you can do that like this.

```
\begin{frame}[t]
...
\end{frame}
```

If you want to align all the frames at the top, add the `t` option when loading the beamer class.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
```